# The relation between two representations whose restrictions to a subgroup are the same

Tags: representation-theory, topological-groups

Suppose $G$ is a compact topological group and $H$ is a closed subgroup whose index in $G$ might be infinite. Let $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ be two continuous representations on the finite dimensional linear space $V$ over a topological field $k$, i.e. we have continuous homomorphisms
\begin{equation}
\rho_i :G \rightarrow \text{GL}(V), i=1,2
\end{equation}
Suppose their restrictions to $H$ is the same, $\rho_1 |_H=\rho_2 |_H$, what is the difference between the two representations?

My guess is that there exists a one dimensional representation $\phi:G \rightarrow k^\times$ whose restriction to $H$ is trivial and
\begin{equation}
\rho_1=\rho_2 \otimes \phi
\end{equation}
Since the representations of compact topological groups are determined by their characters, I tried to prove this using characters, but got stuck. Could anyone prove this statement or give a counter example?

Comment: Observe: If $H$ is trivial, then every representation restricted to $H$ is identical (keeping $V$ fixed, of course).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you.